# Baffled by Javascript setInterval examples vs. actually working/nonworking behavior

Tags: javascript, syntax, setinterval

Numerous examples, on stackoverflow and elsewhere, show setInterval calling a function by name, followed by interval parameter. As in, it makes sense that the following would work:

```
function sayHi() { window.alert('hello')}       
window.setInterval(sayHi, 1000)
```

Also tried (though this is not the way examples show it)

```
window.setInterval(sayHi(), 1000)
```

But it does not (nor any variations of very simple functions). I can only get it to work by "spelling out" the function within the setInterval statement, like so:

```
window.setInterval(function(){window.alert('hello')}, 1000)
```

Any information about this much appreciated.

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)

Comment: sayHi function returns nothing, when you invoke it right away when you pass it to setInterval actually you are passing nothing to it.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The standard parameters for `setInterval` are a function, and an interval.

`window.setInterval(sayHi(), 1000);` wouldn't work as `sayHi()` is not a function, it's undefined. `sayHi` is a function, not `sayHi()`.

`window.setInterval(sayHi, 1000)` is the way to do it.

Because `sayHi` is equal to `function(){window.alert('hello')}`

`window.setInterval(sayHi(), 1000);` is the same as `window.setInterval(function(){window.alert('hello')}, 1000) ;`

After testing, both work, are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hi - thanks alot, I have a simple example working now. I'm still not sure why stuff wasn't working previously (foolishly overwrote example which I *thought* was identical to what I just did.) Will see if it works as it should when in a more complicated context.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is executing the function `sayHi`

```
window.setInterval(sayHi(), 1000)
                        ^
                        |
                        +--- The setTinterval function
                             is receiving an undefined value,
                             rather than a function.
```

Because of that, this code works

```
window.setInterval(sayHi, 1000)  
                       ^
                       |
                       +--- setTinterval receives a function, that
                            will be executed in the future.
```

So, basically, you need to pass a function object to be able to get it works.

Another example is executing the function `sayHi()` which returns a function:

```js
var id;
function sayHi() {
  return function() {      // This is the function that setInterval
    window.alert('hello'); // will execute in the future.
    clearInterval(id);
  }
}

var id = window.setInterval(sayHi(), 1000)
```